# Горизонтальная навигация с разбросом свободного пространства внутрь айтем

Tags: html, css

Имеется навигационное меню:
[image]

Задаюсь вопросом: как раскидать горизонтальные отступы так, чтобы в каждом компоненте было поровну?

1. Можно раскидать компоненты как **text-align: justify**, но тогда пространство вокруг текста будет некликабельно.
2. Можно попробовать флексы с **justify-content: space-around**, но то же самое.
3. Можно сделать табличкой. Но тогда пространство вокруг текста раскидается пропорционально содержимому, а не поровну.
4. Ну и остается пробег с замерами ширин жаба-скриптом.

Вопрос: не появилось ли у нас новых инструментов для решения этой задачи?

Comment: padding для ссылки?

Comment: Разумеется, padding для ссылки :) Но сколько этого padding`а?

Comment: Ну, наверное, пока пункты меню не начнут выпадать из родителя.

Comment: Вы предлагаете подогнать значения padding`а вплотную, так чтобы текст вмещался только? Это плохой вариант. При изменении текста все взорвется: случатся переносы строк или компоненты выйдут заграницу. В этом случае даже погрешность отображения шрифта разуплотнит компонент и бам! Немногим лучше был бы вариант просто проставить все ширины ручками.

Comment: Так вы хотите ширину одинаковую или отступ?

Comment: Ширина компонентов меню пропорциона содержимому текста в них. Отступы внутри не пропорционы, они одинаковы для каждого компонента. Представьте это таким образом: берется ширина всей менюшки, из нее вычитается суммарная ширина всех текстов. Оставшееся место поровну разбрасывается на padding`и. Это очень похоже на justify-content: space-around, но только свободное пространство распространяется не вокруг айтемов, а внутрию

Comment: Погуглите flexbox, возможно, это то, что вам нужно. Либо тупо реализовать данный алгоритм на JS.

Comment: Ну, это мои варианты 2. и 4. Флексы делают то, что нужно, но не для случая с меню. Компоненты меню должны быть кликабельны, и это пространство space-around должно уходить внутрь компонентов. JS-ку написал, пока остановился на ней. Но задача важная, хотелось бы научится реализовывать ее версткой.

Answer (score 1):

Делаем так:

- Устанавливаем вид блока: `display: table;`
- Задаем этому блоку любую ширину
- Задаем способ расчета ширины ячеек внутри блока: `table-layout: fixed;`

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/kbswut3j/)**

Comment: Спасибо, но это не то, что нужно. С *table-layout: fixed* будут компоненты либо одинаковой ширины, либо заданной ручками. Ни то ни другое не подходит.

Comment: @Cypher, я написал ответ до вашего комментария. Давайте еще кое-что уточним:  

 * Элементов в меню фиксированное количество или произвольное?
 * Если произвольное, то как должно происходить вытеснение невлезающих пунктов меню в контейнер? Должен происходить перенос новых пунктов на следующую строку?
 * Какова максимальная ширина меню?
 * Поддержка каких браузеров нужна?

Comment: Хочется найти решение в общем виде (как, например table-layout: fixed на случай, когда компоненты одинаковой ширины - тут не важна ни ширина текста, ни количество компонентов). Но, разумеется, будут естественные ограничения. Никто не будет заталкивать в меню 100500 компонентов и если оно вдруг сильно разрастется, то понятно, что это будет решаться на уровне дизайна. На том сайте, что я сейчас верстаю, это меню встречается на разных страницах с разными компонентами.

Comment: - произвольное, но в рамках разумного, 4-6 штук
- все компоненты всегда вмещаются в одну строку
- ширина меню фиксированная 1000px
- с поддержкой проблем нет, как базовую версию я использую display: table для всяких там IE8. Это не совсем то, что надо, но в качестве рабочей базы пойдет. Дальше можно "улучшить" флексами, трансформами или еще чем.